# Find out if a item was approved

Tags: 2010, approval-process

is it possible to find out if a item was "approved" in the past 
although the item state is now  "pending"?

I tried this caml query, but it does not work:

```
<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='PublishingStartDate'/></IsNotNull></Where>
```

I also tried to filter by the field "_level" or "_UIVersion" but all that did not produce the desired result.

Comment: are you looking to do it programmatically using API calls?

Comment: yes i am working on a custom Lookup-Pickerdialog (SimpleQueryControl)

Comment: Can you please add what all stuff have you already tried to the question?

Comment: If the version is 1.0 or higher, it has to have been approved.

Comment: @PirateEric I believe that this is not right. It is possible that a new version is created when a element is processed (without to approve it)  (look at the versioning settings of a list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SP Doesn't search historical versions in any out of the box setups that I'm aware of. SP limits the searching capabilities to published versions. There are third party tools that do this however.

If you wanted to have this information going forward, you could set up a Yes/No Field with a Approved?" as the label - and make it hidden on new forms. Have a workflow set it to "yes" when Status = Approved. Because it's hidden on new forms users won't be able to change it. Then it's searchable and sortable.

Comment: I will do it so